# Compare value in two data frame; move values between data frames based on value

Tags: r, merge

I have been unable to find an answer. There probably is one on stackoverflow... but I have not found one that I can use.

---

I have two data frames (db.1 and db.larger). what I need to do is:

```
if db.1$ID == db.larger$ID
db1$Gender <- db.larger$Gender
```

I need to copy the Gender value from db.larger to db.1 if the ID is a match.

- Both data frames are between 500.000 rows and six million.
- db.1 contains duplicates as more columns not shown in this example contain unique and vital information that I must keep.
- both data frames contain more columns than shown
- the ID values are characters as they can contain leading zeros.

I have been unable to use match as there are more than one occurrences of persons in db.1

Merge has not worked for me as it adds more data (columns) to the data frames than I want.

---

Here are the example output files:

```
db.1 <- structure(list(ID = c("453", "286", "345", "853", "675", "754","445", "564", "651", "685", "453", "286", "345"), Gender = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Name = c("Rashad Lawrence", "Ali Santana", "Cordell Cobb", "Amani Bennett", "Donavan Frank", "Jeffrey Michael", "Aliana Trujillo", "Cheyanne Wyatt", "Kayden Padilla", "Jasmine Glass", "Rashad Lawrence", "Ali Santana", "Cordell Cobb"), Score = c(0, 0.044, 0.822, 0.322, 0.394, 0.309, 0.826, 0.729, 0.318, 0.6, 0.648, 0.547, 0.53)), .Names = c("ID", "Gender","Name", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
db.larger <- structure(list(ID = c("123", "158", "286", "345", "445", "453", "469", "546", "564", "566", "651", "675", "682", "685", "741", "754", "789", "852", "853", "963"), Gender = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), Name = c("Dexter Holmes", "Roman Macias", "Ali Santana", "Cordell Cobb", "Aliana Trujillo", "Rashad Lawrence", "Preston Mckee", "Kyra Howe", "Cheyanne Wyatt", "Tobias Hart", "Kayden Padilla", "Donavan Frank", "Jamie Yoder", "Jasmine Glass", "Jamar Carter", "Jeffrey Michael", "Erick Tate", "Darion Graves", "Amani Bennett", "Regina Sanders")), .Names = c("ID", "Gender", "Name"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: de-duplicate `db.1` first and select only the columns you want, then use `match` or `merge`. `db.2 = unique(db.1[c("ID", "Gender")])`, then `merge(db.larger, db.2, all.x = T)`.

Comment: I can't delete duplicates as columns not shown in example contain vital information. I will update output files to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not telling you to delete them entirely, just not including them in the subset of data that you merge. After the `merge` you can use `ifelse` or some implementation of `coalesce` (`dplyr` has one) to combine the `Gender` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you always have missing values in `db.1$Gender`, you can delete this column and then perform an `inner_join` from `dplyr`. This procedure keeps the duplicates in `db.1`.

```
library(dplyr)

db.1 <- db.1 %>%
select(-Gender)

db.combine <- inner_join(db.1,db.larger, by = "ID")

db.combine
    ID          Name.x Gender          Name.y
1  453 Rashad Lawrence      1 Rashad Lawrence
2  286     Ali Santana      2     Ali Santana
3  345    Cordell Cobb      1    Cordell Cobb
4  853   Amani Bennett      1   Amani Bennett
5  675   Donavan Frank      2   Donavan Frank
6  754 Jeffrey Michael      2 Jeffrey Michael
7  445 Aliana Trujillo      1 Aliana Trujillo
8  564  Cheyanne Wyatt      2  Cheyanne Wyatt
9  651  Kayden Padilla      2  Kayden Padilla
10 685   Jasmine Glass      2   Jasmine Glass
11 453 Rashad Lawrence      1 Rashad Lawrence
12 286     Ali Santana      2     Ali Santana
13 345    Cordell Cobb      1    Cordell Cobb
```

Your `Name` variables are apparently not perfect matches, you could simply delete either `Name.x` or `Name.y` using `select`, however.

Comment: I would prefer not deleting anything as I do not know if the column will always be NA.

Comment: You can also go for a `full_join`, which will retain all data in both data frames: `db.combine <- full_join(db.larger,db.1, by = "ID")`